about a very simple test on oscillation period on a pendulum
I have made a very simple test on a pendulum on checking the consistency on the obtained oscillation period.
If I don’t complete the inertia tensor parameters, I obtain, when I do the simulation, the good result for the oscillation period of the dynamic of a bar which turns around a fix frame (T = 1.63 s).
But, personally, I didn’t understand why I don’t have to complete the I33 parameter with the inertia 1/12 * m * L² which is the inertia of a bar calculated at the center of the bar. If i complete the I33 parameter, I don’t find the right period (around T = 1.94 s).
Do you have ideas why I didn’t have to complete the inertia tensor in this simple example of the pendulum ?
I precise that I want to ckeck the oscillation period of a physical pendulum (a bar turning around a fix point and not a simple pendulum a mass with a massless wire.
Here a picture of the mechanism i would like to model to be more clear.

The data is simple :

a distributed bar,
a mass m = 1 kg,
a length L = AB = 1 m.

Here a reminding of the theorical results of the calculation of the oscillation period for the physical pendulum et simple that i would like to retrieve with Modelica models using the Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Parts.Body and Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Parts.BodyShape component

I expect a better understanding of the Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Parts.Body and Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Parts.BodyShape component with regard to the inertia terms.

Can you add a reference to the model you used, e.g. Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Examples.Elementary.Pendulum or upload the custom model if you created one?

you can directly use this one indeed Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Examples.Elementary.Pendulum. The question is why I33 is not completed by I33 = 1/12 * m * L² ?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@Community thank you for your feedback, how can I upload Modelica files ?

The issue seems to be understanding the parameters of  Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Parts.Body and Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Parts.BodyShape
especially in the Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Examples.Elementary.Pendulum example.
For those model:

The inertia parameters are with respect to the center of mass
rCM is the vector between the flange and the center of mass.

Specifically, rCM isn't describing a bar with distributed mass (as you seem to assume), but a mass-less bar to the center of mass (but with inertia and mass at the center of mass). If you want to use a rectangular or cylindrical bar you can use Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Parts.BodyBox or Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Parts.BodyCylinder (and they already contain that formula).
Setting rCM=0 and adding a Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Parts.FixedTranslation with the same parameter should give the same result.
For the new information it is important to remember that the simple analytical formula is a linearization that is only valid for very small oscillations.
The Modelica model is a correct physical model including non-linearities and is thus valid for large oscillations as well.
If we simulate the example model a bit further we get that the first period is 1.6 s, but then (due to the damping decreasing the amplitude) it decreases to 1.5 s and 1.43 s, and eventually down to 1.42 s (corresponding to the analytical solution for small oscillations).

The problem with Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Parts.BodyBox or Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Parts.BodyCylinder comes from the fact that the inertia of te body is computed from the geometry and the density. Consequently, i prefer to use Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Parts.Body and Modelica.Mechanics.MultiBody.Parts.BodyShape in which you can directly enter the inertia.
Normally, in the example pendulum, it was as you mentioned (only a mass located at L = 0.5 m), i should find a period of T = 2 pi / omega with omega = Sqrt[g/0.5] T= 1.41 s whereas the Modelica model gives T = 1.63 s.

i add more information in my initial question
